# Exclude duplicate values in one table and return the remaining

Tags: mysql

I have a table like so:

```
table: album_image(album_id, image_id)

album_id    image_id
----------------------------
87          2326
87          2325
86          2325
85          5689
89          56
```

Having 2 album id's (let's say 87 and 86), I want to extract only the image_id that are not in those 2 albums.

So, for example, if i have album_id 87 and 86, it should return image_id : 2326

How do i go about doing the query?

Comment: image_id 2326 is in album 87. did you mean it should return 5689 and 56?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please explain the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the requirement looks like we need to find the image which is either on album_id 86 or 87 but not both, and this could be done using `group by` and `having count`

```
select 
image_id from album_image 
where album_id in (87,86) 
group by image_id having count(*)=1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Version with not in operator (minus operator doesn't exist in mysql to do such thing):

```
select image_id from album_image
where album_id = 86
      and image_id not in (select image_id 
                                 from album_image 
                                 where album_id = 87)
union
select image_id from album_image
where album_id = 87
      and image_id not in (select image_id 
                                 from album_image 
                                 where album_id = 86)
```

Also possible with an outer join.

Comment: this solution returns values found in both tables

Comment: My mistake ;-) In the subselect i put "image_id=8x" instead of "album_id=8x". Fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
select image_id from album_image where album_id not in (86, 87)
```

Comment: In the sample data, this should return two records.

Comment: noap, in this sample data it should return one record: 2326